# Make fastcopy default copy operation

Tags: windows

Can I make [Fastcopy](http://ipmsg.org/tools/fastcopy.html.en) default copy operation to replace window copy, like what [Teracopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php) does ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program has to actually support that feature. Or you can write your own shell extension.

But since the source code is available, you can modify it.

Comment: Now I only can copy and paste after right-click. Can I copy and paste with Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V like Teracopy ?

Comment: Again, The program has to support it. More specifically, Fast Copy has to have a shell extension in order to support that functionality.

Comment: Not just a shell extension, FastCopy has that, but it has to implement a copy handler and override Explorer.